# Java: Google Maps alternative

Tags: java, api, maps

I'm really tired of using the Google Web Toolkit for accessing Google Maps in Java using Netbeans... Does anybody know of a good alternative providing a simple(r) API?

Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: What are your requirements for the API?

Comment: I only need driving instructions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org/) has a good [API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) in combination with [OpenLayers](http://www.openlayers.org/).
Good luck with that!

Driving instructions are included, but since OSM is user-generated, you cannot rely 100% on this information. See [OSM-Wiki article "Routing"](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing)

Answer (score 0):

If you want another API that has great routing and other mapping alternatives with a J2ME API you can take a look
[Shameless plug]
http://developer.decarta.com
[/shameless plug]

We also do mapping, geocoding, and other cool spatial functionality.
We have an android API, iOS API, mobile JS, and a desktop JS along with XML web services.